# EF Core 7 Json column with different column name

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-core

We are trying to migrate from the `HasConversion` option to map ef core properties to .net types which are actually json columns in the database, to the native support for Json columns in ef core 7.

So we used to have something like:

```cs
builder.Property(x => x.Definition).HasConversion(x => x.ToJSON(), x => x.ToObject<ViewDefinition>());
```

and now we are doing:

```cs
builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Definition, nb =>
{
    nb.ToJson();
}
```

however, in our case, the `Definition` isn't called `Definition` in the database, but is called `ViewDefinition`. However, we need the property in the ef entity to be called `ViewDefinition`. Now it seems that the `OwnsOne` setup ignores the `[Column("ViewDefinition")]` attribute on the property, and I can also not find any way to set the name of the property in the builder.

Now my question is, what can I do in my ef configuration to make sure the `Definition` property maps to the `ViewDefinition` column in sql server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that `[Column("ViewDefinition")]` isn´t currently picked up for `ToJson()` mapped properties.

Instead, you should use the `ToJson` builder extension to specify the alternate name as shown below;

```cs
builder
    .Property(
        entity => entity.Definition,
        builder => builder.ToJson("ViewDefinition"));
```

fyi `efcore 7.0.8`

Comment: Yeah I just came here to answer my own question, but you already did. If only everything in life turned out to be this easy

Comment: life wouldn't be valued. I was facing the issue myself, and ended up here thankfully I got to a solution the same day.